# Hide and show list items of divs after nth item

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Say I have an unordered list, like so:

**HTML Code :**

```
<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
   <li>One 1</li>
   <li>Two 2</li>
   <li>Three 3</li>
   <li>Four 4</li>
   <li>Five 5</li>
   <li>One 11</li>
   <li>Two 22</li>
   <li>Three 33</li>
   <li>Four 44</li>
   <li>Five 55</li>
</ul>
```

How would i using jquery or javascript , show only first five list items and have a 'show more' text there , so when clicked upon , the next five list items would be appear?

**Script :**

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var max = 4
    if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="sub_accordian"><span class="show_more">(see more)</span></li>');
        $('.sub_accordian').click( function(){
            $(this).siblings(':gt('+max+')').toggle();
            if ( $('.show_more').length ) {
                $(this).html('<span class="show_less">(see less)</span>');
            } else {
                $(this).html('<span class="show_more">(see more)</span>');
            };
        });
    };
});
```

when i click on 'show more' it should be visible next five results . Once every results loaded 'show more' text would be changed on 'less more'.

and when i clicked upon the 'less more' button first results should be visible other list items should be hide and 'less more' text changed to 'show more'

Comment: Whats the problem with this code?

Comment: need to show hide only by five i guess

Comment: What about using a sub ul?

Comment: @guradio: need to show only first five list click on show more next five list items should be visible and show more text should be changed to less more

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `ul > li:not(":visible"):lt(5)` selector like following.

```js
$('.show_more').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'see more') {
    $('.parent > li:not(":visible"):lt(5)').show();
  } else {
    $(this).text('see more');
    $('.parent > li:gt(4)').hide();
  }

  var notVisible = $('.parent > li:not(":visible")').length;

  if (notVisible == 0) {
    $(this).text('see less');
  }
}).click();
```

```css
.parent > li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li>One
    <ul>
      <li>on 1.1</li>
      <li>on 1.2</li>
      <li>on 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>One 1</li>
  <li>Two 2</li>
  <li>Three 3</li>
  <li>Four 4</li>
  <li>Five 5</li>
  <li>One 11</li>
  <li>Two 22</li>
  <li>Three 33</li>
  <li>Four 44</li>
  <li>Five 55</li>
</ul>
<span class="show_more">see more</span>
```

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/63bkkmbf/15/)

Comment: :your previous code would be fine . Issue is when i click on 'show more' it should be visible next five results .

Onces every results loaded 'show more' text would be changed on 'less more'

Comment: I am try to add css "display: none;" it should be hide full list also

Comment: What do you want? Hide all when click `less more`. @Mgr

Comment: when i click on less more it should hide all the list but not hide on first five results

Comment: problem is this code consider for all child list of li also . see https://jsfiddle.net/mgobinath30/63bkkmbf/6/

Comment: Add a class to outer most `ul`. See updated answer & fiddle. @Mgr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a click handler like

```js
$('ul').has('li:nth-child(6)').append('<li class="more">Show more</li><li class="less">Show less</li>');

$('ul .more').click(function() {
  $(this).next().show();
  var $nexts = $(this).parent().children('li:not(.more, .less):visible:last').nextAll(':not(.more, .less)');
  $nexts.slice(0, 5).show();
  $(this).toggle($nexts.length > 5);
});
$('ul .less').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().show();
  var $curr = $(this).parent().children('li:not(.more, .less):visible');
  var num = $curr.length % 5 || 5;
  $curr.slice(-num).hide();
  $(this).toggle($curr.length > 10);
});
```

```css
li:nth-child(n+6):not(.more) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>One 1</li>
  <li>Two 2</li>
  <li>Three 3</li>
  <li>Four 4</li>
  <li>Five 5</li>
  <li>One 11</li>
  <li>Two 22</li>
  <li>Three 33</li>
  <li>Four 44</li>
  <li>Five 55</li>
  <li>Extra</li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to have only one navigation button available at a time

```js
var $uls = $('ul').has('li:nth-child(6)').append('<li class="more">Show more</li>');

$uls.on('click', '.more', function() {
  var $nexts = $(this).parent().children('li:not(.more):visible:last').nextAll(':not(.more)');
  $nexts.slice(0, 5).show();
  if ($nexts.length <= 5) {
    $(this).toggleClass('more less').text('Show less')
  }
});
$uls.on('click', '.less', function() {
  var $curr = $(this).parent().children('li:not(.less):visible');
  var num = $curr.length % 5 || 5;
  $curr.slice(-num).hide();
  if ($curr.length <= 10) {
    $(this).toggleClass('more less').text('Show more')
  }
});
```

```css
li:nth-child(n+6):not(.more):not(.less) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>One 1</li>
  <li>Two 2</li>
  <li>Three 3</li>
  <li>Four 4</li>
  <li>Five 5</li>
  <li>One 11</li>
  <li>Two 22</li>
  <li>Three 33</li>
  <li>Four 44</li>
  <li>Five 55</li>
  <li>Extra</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: show more should be changed show less ,in this example both should be available